# Line-height not being inherited in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

Within Outlook only, text does not inherit the line-height property from any parent element that's nested more than two elements above.

For example, the line-height is applied to these:

```
<div style="line-height:150%">
    Text
</div>
```

```
<div style="line-height:150%">
    <td>
        Text
    </td>
</div>
```

*(Edit: although the second one works, it is incorrect to put a td inside a div)*

But not if the style is inline on the body tag or a parent beyond the immediate td the text is in

I have tried combinations of the following:

- With and without `mso-line-height-rule: exactly;` before and after line-height style
- Line-height value as percents and points (150% and 1.5), I believe only percents work in Outlook, but I tried both anyways *(Edit: Thank you for the comment explaining the difference between the two!)*
- Placing the style on different elements (td, tr, table, body, etc), only div seems to work, as seen in the examples above
- Removing the `margin` style property from all elements (I read somewhere that margin can mess with Outlook processing styles, but no dice)

The reason this is an issue for me is because I am building emails in Salesforce, I would like to be able to apply the 150% line-height to the template so we don't need to change the line-height for each block individually that's created.

Does anyone with hyper-specific Outlook development knowledge know of a fix or workaround? Or will I just need to apply the line-height to the individual text blocks to accommodate for Outlook?

---

*Edit:*

I've learned that using a div inside a table is an error unless it is inside a td

So I guess my main puzzlement is why Outlook won't render line-height in any element that ISN'T a div. Yet another Outlook mystery lol

Comment: Note that putting a td in a div is an error and you may just be looking at Outlook's error handling. Also note that there is a considerable difference between line-height with and without a unit. With a unit (like 150%) the value is calculated first and then inherited; in `<div><h1></h1></div>` if the div's line-height is 150%, then the h1 will get the exactly same line height as the div, even if its font is bigger. If the div's line-height is 1.5, the h1's line-height will become 1.5* its own font size.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's simple, Outlook seems to preserve styling in the `<head>`.

So this works across all email clients for infinite nesting:

```
<style type="text/css">
  td {
    line-height:150%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: My experience has been that Outlook does not render any styling that isn't inline, at least in the desktop application. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: @Holly Outlook will ignore most styles, but not all of them. This has been tested in Litmus and works in Outlook. Did you try it?